# Handling GPO Policies between different domains

Tags: group-policy, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

I have a handful of changes in a policy that I'd like to apply to other domains. I am wanting to copy this policy to these other domains so I do not have to create them for every dc.

Most of what I've seen said to right click the GPO and backup but I don't have that option. The other way was to do the following: "In the Group Policy Management Console tree, click Change Control in the forest and domain in which you want to manage GPOs.". I cannot find where the Change Control option is located.

Am I going at this the wrong way or is this not possible? I'm just trying to save time and not have to redo the policy for each domain.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `Group Policy Management` expand `Group Policy Objects` (You'll see all your GPOs listed here), if you right click on a GPO you'll get the option to Backup. You'll not see the option on a linked GPO outside of this container.

Comment: @jfrmilner thank you for the info! I was able to find the backup option. How do I go about restoring it on another domain? It's saying no backups found when I select the backed up folder that I copied over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying and importing GPOs from another forest (high level)

1. Create a Backup in the source domain. Using `Group Policy Management` expand `Group Policy Objects` (You'll see all your GPOs listed here), if you right click on a GPO you'll get the option to Backup. You'll not see the option on a linked GPO outside of this container.
2. Create a new GPO in the target domain.
3. Import the settings from the backup file into the GPO created in the previous step. Found on the Right-Click menu of the new GPO.
4. (Optional - Use [Migration Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/gpmc/using-migration-tables)).
   Migration tables are files that are created by an administrator. They are used to implement the advanced capabilities of Group Policy object (GPO) import and copy operations. A migration table can contain information about references to security principals, to Universal Naming Convention (UNC) paths, or to both. By using a migration table, an administrator can modify references to security principals and to UNC paths during import and copy operations. A sample migration table template is provided in the Program Files\GPMC\Scripts folder on computers on which the Group Policy Management Console (GPMC) is installed. For more information about the syntax that is used by migration tables, see this sample migration table. An administrator can create a simple migration table by saving a copy of the sample migration table and then modifying the copy as needed. The GPMC also provides interfaces so you can automate the creation and editing of migration tables.